# EditText.setError() popup placement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, scrollview

I'm using the v16 API and having problems with where the popup is being placed when the onscreen keyboard is displayed.

The first problem is that if the `EditText` is at the bottom of the screen, when I touch the field to open it for editing the popup is displayed below the control and the immediately covered as the keyboard appears.  It doesn't reposition itself above the `EditText` until a keypress triggers my validation code to fire again on the new value.

The second problem is that when I close the keyboard and the `ScrollView` containing the text scrolls back down from where it positioned itself to show the `EditText` above the keyboard the popup remains placed on the upper half of the screen instead of where the `EditText` is until I touch something else on the screen (triggering the ScrollView to do a redraw???).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that popup has various problems like this :(

Perhaps a simple solution in your case is to forcibly invalidate the UI when the keyboard has displayed and dismissed? Can't recall if the Popup will reposition if the EditText is invalidated, but worth trying as the alternative may be to re-implement.

Checkout my android-formidable-validation lib on github, it re-implements...though has its own problems - if you go down that path, why not give me a hand with some contributions ;)

Comment: Where are you on github?  Doing a usersearch for "straya" didn't turn up anything.

Comment: invalidation of either the editText or it's parent do not trigger a redraw of the popup in the correct location.

Comment: Sorry Dan, thought you would've been able to search for the project name (you could have ;P), here's the link: https://github.com/coreform/android-formidable-validation

Comment: Hmm, OK so invalidation failed but what about setting the setError text again? Perhaps that'll yield the redraw of the Error Popup?

Comment: I tried resetting the error text (and after that the regular text) in events fired when they keyboard displayed.  Bafflingly both stopped the ScrollView from scrolling; leaving the EditText completely under the keyboard.